# Preg_replace pattern for BBCode quote tag

Tags: php, regex

I want to use the PHP preg_replace function on two strings but I am unsure of the regular expression to use.

For the **first** string, I only require the author value (so everything after `author=`, but nothing after the space):

```
[quote author=username link=1150111054/0#7 date=1150151926]
```

Result:

```
[quote=username]
```

For the **second** string, there is no `author=` tag. The username simply appears after a closed open quote

```
[quote] username link=1142890417/0#43 date=1156429613]
```

Ideally, the result should be:

```
[quote=username]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the string `author=` and `]` as optional inorder to do replacement on both type of strings.

**Regex:**

```
^\[(\S+?)\]?\s+(?:author=)?(\S+).*$
```

If you want to mention the string `quote` on your regex then use this,

```
^\[(quote)\]?\s+(?:author=)?(\S+).*$
```

**Replacement string:**

```
[$1=$2]
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/lH2fW8/3)

```
<?php
$string =<<<EOT
[quote author=username link=1150111054/0#7 date=1150151926]
[quote] username link=1142890417/0#43 date=1156429613]
EOT;
echo preg_replace("~^\[(\S+?)\]?\s+(?:author=)?(\S+).*$~m", "[$1=$2]", $string);
?>
```

**Output:**

```
[quote=username]
[quote=username]
```

Comment: This worked well, thanks. I used the second expression to make it less greedy. Is it possible to extend the expression to remove `pid=123456` from the following: `[quote=username pid=123456]` ?

Comment: I am unable to get this to work if for same line strings. I'm trying to make it capture up to the final close square bracket. Example: http://regex101.com/r/zL4jY2/2

Answer (score 1):

For the first one: `/author=(.*?) /`

And for the second one `/\[quote\] (.*?) /`

In you case:

```
$str1 = "[quote author=username link=1150111054/0#7 date=1150151926]";
$str2 = "[quote] username link=1142890417/0#43 date=1156429613]";
$regex1 = '/author=(.*?) /';
$regex2 = '/\[quote\] (.*?) /';
if (preg_match($regex1, $str1, $match1))
    echo '[quote='.$newStr1 = $match1[1].']';
if (preg_match($regex2, $str2, $match2))
    echo '[quote='.$newStr2 = $match2[1].']';
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to handle both with a single regex.

```
 # Find:      '~(?|\[quote\]\s*(\S+).*|\[quote\s+author=\s*(\S+).*)~'
 # Replace:   '[author=$1]'

 (?|
      \[quote\] \s* 
      ( \S+ )
      .* 
   |  
      \[quote \s+ author= \s* 
      ( \S+ )
      .* 
 )
```

Input:

```
[quote author=username link=1150111054/0#7 date=1150151926]
[quote] username link=1142890417/0#43 date=1156429613]
```

Output:

```
[author=username]
[author=username]
```